# Why scipy.integrate shows has no "simpson" attribute?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have some python code which uses function `scipy.integrate.simpson`
So for example I import scipy using `import scipy.integrate as scp_int` and then use it in following way:

`vol_r = scp_int.simpson(f_integrand_r,dx=_dx1,axis=0)`

I get this error

```
    vol_r = scp_int.simpson(f_integrand_r,dx=_dx1,axis=0)
AttributeError: module 'scipy.integrate' has no attribute 'simpson'`
```

I have made sure that I have scipy package installed, using `pip install scipy`, and I have restarted computer. I don't know why is this happening? Can someone give the reason or help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using version 1.5 (or an older version) of SciPy.
If you don't know which version you have installed, you can check with

```
import scipy
print(scipy.__version__)
```

`simpson` was added in 1.6.0; it is the new name for the old function called `simps`.  If you can't upgrade, you should be able to use `simps` instead of `simpson`.